# Space Invaders stick to wall

Tags: c#, visual-studio, list, xna

So I have to develop an XNA game for school and I thought Space Invaders was a nice thing to make. But now I'm stuck with a problem. I have a `List` filled with 'Aliens' from another class. And every second it moves 20 px to the right and I want it to descend when it touches the right side of the screen (not the problem). But I want it to move the opposite direction (to the left) as soon as it touches the wall. Here lies the problem.
As soon as it touches the wall it still moves 20px once, changes direction, moves 20px back and changes direction again. This keeps repeating.
So where lies the problem. I think it has to check earlier if one of the aliens touches the screen but don't know how to accomplish that and thought maybe one of you could help me out because it is very frustrating!

I included the update method

```
if (xPos % step == 0)
{
   if (!isDescending)
   {
      for (int k = 0; k < sprites.Count; k++)
      {
         Sprite sprite = sprites[k];

         if (touchedRight) sprite.position.X += step;
         else sprite.position.X -= step;
      }

      for (int k = 0; k < sprites.Count; k++)
      {
         Sprite sprite = sprites[k];
         bool hitLeft = sprite.position.X == 0;
         bool hitRight = sprite.rect.Right == screenWidth;
         if ((hitLeft) || (hitRight))
         {
            touchedRight = !touchedRight;
            isDescending = true;
         }
      }
   }

   else
   {
      isDescending = false;
      for (int k = 0; k < sprites.Count; k++)
      {
         sprites[k].position.Y += sprites[k].rect.Height;
      }
   }
}
// CheckCollision(alienBounds, k-1);
// sprite.rect = new Rectangle((int)sprite.position.X, (int)sprite.position.Y, 20, 20);
// alienBounds = sprite.rect;
xPos += 1;
```

Comment: I suspect you issue is with your X position check. Rather than checking to see if it is equal to 0 I would see if it is less than or equal to 0 and if it is then, if it is, set it to 0 and change direction. This assumes that the position will then be incremented again before another check, if no then you may have to set it to .01 or some such to keep it from sticking.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Make sure you implement what made Spaceinvaders special from all other games back then. It becomes harder the more monsters you kill. This was due to the fact, that old gaming statios werent sucht good Computers. The more monsters you killed the bigger the relief for the cpu, the faster it could process. So basically, the more monsters you kill the faster the game has to get. (The special thing about this, it was the first game becomming more difficult, the further you have progressed)

Comment: @MikeB You see they even don't get to the most left side. The go 20px too far to the right, go 20px back, go 20px too far again, go 20px back etc etc. so it's like they stick to the right

Comment: Without seeing all the code I was guessing that might be because they are never exactly at 0 but are getting incemented past 0 and then your position is out of the bounds your code expects causing unexpected results. It all depends on how far you are stepping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i made a new rectangle called 'bounds' which is as wide as the aliens and moves the same as the aliens do. And got it working! (half of it). It moves to the right until it touches the right side, then it goes to the left but keeps going to the left and never goes back to the right. So where am i going wrong this time?

```
if (xPos % step == 0)
            {
                if (!isDescending)
                {

                    for (int k = 0; k < sprites.Count; k++)
                    {
                        Sprite sprite = sprites[k];
                        sprite.position.X += step;
                    }

                    if (bounds.Right == screenWidth || bounds.Left == 0)
                    {
                        touchedRight = !touchedRight;
                        step *= -1;
                    }

                    if (!touchedRight) bounds.X += step;
                    if (touchedRight) bounds.X -= step;

                    // for (int k = 0; k < sprites.Count; k++)
                    // {
                    //    Sprite sprite = sprites[k];

                    //    bool hitLeft = sprite.position.X == 0;
                    //    bool hitRight = sprite.rect.Right == screenWidth;
                    //    if ((hitLeft) || (hitRight))
                    //    {
                    //        touchedRight = !touchedRight;
                    //        isDescending = true;
                    //    }
                    // }
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, this is wrong:

```
if ((hitLeft) || (hitRight))
```

When moving right, you only care about `hitRight`.  And when moving left, you care only about `hitLeft`.

So try

```
if (touchedRight? hitLeft: hitRight)
```

This will also fix the issue where multiple aliens can hit the wall at the same time.

Comment: i hope it is really simple as that! I will try it soon (as i will do with the answers given below)

Comment: tried this, but didn't work. They keep moving to the right until they disappear. You're sure this is all adjustments needed? Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: As Mike mentioned in a comment, you should be testing `>=`, not `==`, to see when they hit the right edge.  And `<=` for the left edge test.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure but I bellieve in Space invaders, if you kill all columns but the most left, it doesnt move completely to the right side of the screen before switching its direction.

So what I suggest is you create a derivate of a Sprite called Invader:

```
class Invader : Sprite
{
    readonly float distanceFromCenterHorizontal;

    public Invader(float distanceFromCenterHorizontal)
    {
        this.distanceFromCenterHorizontal= distanceFromCenterHorizontal;
    }

    public void UpdatePosition(Point center)
    {
        this.Position.X = center.X + distanceFromCenterHorizontal;
        this.Position.Y = center.Y;
    }
}



// global variables:
Point center = ....
bool moveLeft = false;

void createInvaders()
{
    int invaderWidth = 20; // whatever your value is
    float columnCenter = ((float) columnMax) / 2 * invaderWidth;

    for(var column = 0; column < columnMax ; column++)
    {
        float invaderX = (column * invaderWidth);

        float distanceFromCenterHorizontal = invaderX - columnCenter;

        for(var row = 0; row < rowMax; row ++)
        {
            Invader invader = new Invader(distanceFromCenterHorizontal);
            invader.Position.Y = row * invaderHeight // Needs adjustment here!
        }
    }
}

void update()
{
    if(center.X == screenWidth) moveLeft = true;
    else if(center.X <= 0) moveLeft = false;

    center.X += moveLeft? -step : step;

    foreach(var invader in invaders) invader.UpdatePosition(center);
}
```

You want to move the "centerPoint" and all Invaders update According to the new Center.

Im not sure if XNA uses double or float values, so youmight need to adjust this.

You can then easily expand this to create some up / down wobbling.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that as you kill columns, the remaining ones do traverse farther.  This is a useful way of slowing down their vertical progress.

Comment: Ok, well then disregard what i wrote :/

Comment: well that sure does look very right! I will try that as soon as i'm able too. I will keep you up to date and thanks for your replies. XNA uses floats btw